# Hadoop configurations seem not to be read

Tags: permissions, hadoop, cygwin, configuration-files, tmp

Every time when I try to start my mapreduce application (in standalone Hadoop), it tries to put stuff in the tmp directory, which it can't:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-username\mapred\staging\username-1524148556\.staging to 0700
```

It ties to use an invalid path (slashes should be the other way around for cygwin).

I set hadoop.tmp.dir in core-site.xml (in the conf folder of Hadoop), but it seems that the config file is never read (if I put syntax errors in the file, it makes no difference). I added:

```
--config /home/username/hadoop-1.0.1/conf
```

To the command, but no difference. I also tried:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/username/hadoop-1.0.1/conf
```

but also that does not seem to have an effect....

Any pointers on why the configs would not be read, or what else I am failing to see here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running a Cygwin version of Hadoop or a Windows version?

Comment: @AlG: I downloaded the linux version from http://apache.mirror.versatel.nl/hadoop/common/hadoop-1.0.1/ , is there a seperate cygwin version? But even then, it should be possible to tell the linux version that it should not use /tmp right?

Comment: I just checked, there isn't a Cygwin version. That odd path is the key, perhaps the Linux version of Hadoop is picking up the windows version of Java?

Comment: Yes, the path is the problem, right now I am going with full linux, since I cannot find the place to configure that path....

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the slashes are inverted, it's that /tmp is a cygwin path which actually maps to /cygwin/tmp or c:\cygwin\tmp.  since hadoop is java and doesn't know about cygwin mappings, it takes /tmp to mean c:\tmp.

there's an awful lot of stuff to patch if you want to get 1.0.1 running on cygwin.

see:  http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/User:Fkorning/Code/Hadoop-on-Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I found the following link useful, it seems that the problem stands with newer version of Hadoop. I'm using version 1.0.4 and I'm still facing this problem.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/25837

UPDATED: in Mahout 0.7 and for the ones who use the "Mahoot in Action" book example, you shoud change the example code as follows:

```
    File outFile = new File("output");
    if (!outFile.exists()) {
        outFile.mkdir();
    }
    Path output = new Path("output");
    HadoopUtil.delete(conf, output);

    KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("testdata/points"), new Path("testdata/clusters"),
            output, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 0.001, 10,
            true, 0.1, true);
```